# Xamarin Image usage for iOS , Android and PCL

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios, xamarin.android, xamarin.forms

‪I am confused about the usage of images in Xamarin. For iOS images I am using sampleimage@2x.png. How does the image sizes relate to Android? I know Android doesn't like @2x in the image name. If I am skipping @2x and use sampleimage.png for Android then what common image name should I be using in PCL project.

Comment: https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/user-interface/images/
Different platforms will pick up images from different folders from embedded resources if you do carefully read the above article.

Answer (score 1):

If you have an image named as icon_detail.

In resources file of ios project you should add three different sizes of this icon_detail image.

For example

first icon: 25*25 sizes => icon_detail.png

second icon: 50*50 sizes => icon_detail@2x.png

third icon: 75*75 sizes => icon_detail@3x.png

In android it is a little bit different

You should add icons with same name but different sizes.

For example

first icon : 25*25 sizes => icon_detail.png to drawable-hdpi file under resources

second icon : 50*50 sizes => icon_detail.png to drawable-xhdpi file under resources

third icon : 75*75 sizes => icon_detail.png to drawable-xxhdpi file under resources

Comment: What image source I should refer to in PCL project? For example: Content.BackgroundImage="icon_image.png?